# Permutation on word if E,F,G have to stay in order

Tags: permutations

Im stuck on a problem which I have answered and need help to verifiy if I have done/understood it correctly.

**Problem**
If we have the following string: `A,A,B,C,D,D,D,E,F,G`
How many ways are there to rearrange the letters if the Letters, E,F,G have to appear in the same order.

**My approach**
I first decided to find the permutation of the letters except E,F,G and deal with these 3 last. So i ended up with $\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4}{2!\cdot3!}$ 
And now that there are 3 more letters left. (The last three) and that they have to appear in order, we have no choice other than placing the letters on order. i.e `E,F,G`

So the final answer is $\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1}{2!\cdot3!}$

**Question**
I would like to know if I have attempted this problem correctly. If not could you point out where i have gone wrong and/or give me some hints?

**Edit**
`E,F,G` doesn't have to appear in next to eachother

Comment: When you say "appear in order, do you mean that they have to appear like $EFG$ or do they not have to be next to each other as long as E comes (not necessarily directly) before F, which comes before G?

Comment: @user92774 E,F,G doesn't have to appear in next to eachother

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of ways to arrange all $10$ letters is found from the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient#Multinomial_coefficients) as:

$$\binom{10}{3,2,1,1,1,1,1} = \frac{10!}{3!2!1!1!1!1!1!}=302,400$$

Then for each ordering of all $10$ letters if we think of keeping all but those in the set $S=\{E,F,G\}$ fixed then there are $3!$ ways to arrange the elements in $S$.  If we divide the above number by $3!=6$ we get the answer you're looking for which is $50,400$.

Comment: thanks for your answer, you explained it really well! just one more thing, what if the last three letters were {E,E,F}? How would I go about doing that then, would it just be the same: divide by 3!

Comment: Not quite, first your count of the number of orderings of all $10$ letters would be slightly different since the multiplcity of $E$s went from one to two.  Can you use the definition of the multinomial coefficient to figure this out?  Finally you need to divide by the number of distinct orderings of $\{E,E,F\}$ which is also counted using the multinomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

You said the E, F, and G have to appear in order. Do they have to appear consecutively?

If so, then your approach started out correct; finding all the possible 7-letter words of the remaining letters and inserting the string "EFG" in various places would yield the answer. However, you would want 7-letter words:

$\cfrac{7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{3!\cdot2!} = 420$

(so you would not start the multiplication with $10$)

After this, there are eight places to insert the string "EFG" (before the first letter, between the first and second letters, between the second and third, etc.)

So $8\cdot420 = 3360$

If E, F, and G do NOT have to appear consecutively, the problem becomes a bit more difficult.

Comment: A bit more difficult? Not really. First find the number of ways to place the letters EFG in between each already existing letter and then divide by 6 since only the order $EFG$ is allowed.

Comment: @user92774, nice insight. You should write that up as an alternative answer.

Comment: There are already too many answers for this question. And if I were to solve it in an even better way, I would just find $\frac{10!}{2!3!}$ (permutations of all of the letters regardless of order) and divide that by $6$, as Patrick did.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that order of E,F,G would be same and E,F,G can appear anywhere in the 10 letter string, not necessarily consecutively.

So, First select 3 out of 10 positions, where to put E,F,G that would be

$$\binom{10}{3} = \frac{10.9.8}{3.2} = 120$$

Further, permuting 7 alphabets gives you 420.

So the answer would be $120*420 = 50400$

Answer (score 0):

First permute the non-ordered letters in the multiset $\{A^2, B^1, C^1, D^3\}$, which gives you
$$\binom{7}{2, 1, 1, 3} = \frac{7!}{2! 1! 1! 3!} = 420$$
Next there are 8 positions for the other 3 letters, you need to pick 3 of them, for
$$\binom{8}{3} = \frac{8!}{3! 5!} = 56$$
I.e., in all:
$$\binom{7}{2, 1, 1, 3} \binom{8}{3} = 420 \cdot 56 = 23520$$

Comment: can i please ask you, how do you write in mathematical form, I am new here, so I need help to write like this on stackexchange, I would be grateful, ty

Comment: I don't think this is completely right.  First there would be $8$ positions assuming you mean the $6$ spots between the first $7$ letters plus the two endpoints but also you could certainly have $AAEFGBCDDD$ as a possible string which your formula wouldn't account for.

Comment: @Patrick, thanks. Had found out my error before your comment.

Comment: I think this is still incorrect, there are 10 positions overall due to 10 alphabets, so for picking E, F, G you would select 3 out of 10 first, that is C(10,3) * 420.

Comment: @abstractnature, that is just a subset of LaTeX. Take a peek [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @abstractnature, for a systematic way of handling such cases (letters that repeat) you need the enlightenment of the [Tao of BOOKKEEPER](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2010/lecture-notes/MIT6_042JS10_lec28_sol.pdf).

Comment: @vonbrand to fix your solution, instead of multiplying by 56 multiply by $8*9*10$ and then divide by 6. There's 8 positions for the first letter, 9 for the next, and 10 for the last. Then divide by 6 because $EFG$ is one of 6 permutations of those letters.